# Update One2many Fields in the view

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have a model A which has an one2mny relation with another model B and the later has also an one2many relation with a model C.
I want to use self.update to update the one2many relation in the model A in and onchange method so accordingly update the one2many relation in the model B.
I have managed to update the first one but the second one is not updated here what i have done :

```
temp.append((0,0,{
    'periode':periode,
    'ca':ca,
    'loc':loc,
    'line_rs':line_rsc,
}))
self.update({
    'periode_line':temp
})
```

where line_rsc is a list that should be used to update the second 
one2many relation

Thanks

Comment: what kind of api you are using

Comment: i use the odoo 8

Answer (score 0):

i tried this using the new api and it seems to be working just fine:

```
 # this will add the new record to existing records
 @api.onchange(..)
 def .....(self):
    self.update(
        {'o2m_1_field': [{
                        'o2m_1_field_name': 'value',
                        'o2m_1_field_o2m_2_name': [{'o2m_2_field': 'value'}]
                    }]
        }
    )
```

this logic works fine in new api.
or you can do it like this

```
    # this will add the new record to existing records
    self.o2m_1_field += self.env['o2m.1.model.name'].new({
                        'o2m_1_field_name': 'value',
                        'o2m_1_field_o2m_2_name': [{'o2m_2_field': 'value'}]
                    })
```

if this is not working for you and giving you bad query error then you need to 
use the latest version of odoo 8 because a lot has been changing you can even
do onchange on a o2m_field now ...

Comment: can you put a picture of your view does it has two one2many ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: image 1]

secod pic (secod one2many relation):

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]